# Git only works partially (some git commands are found, other not)

Tags: windows-7, git, cmd.exe

Having some trouble with git today (worked lovely yesterday and can't figure out what changed)

This is the scenario:
The path is setup correctly and points to the git file, when using cmd OR the git bash only some commands give the correct output. For example:

```
$ git
usage: git [--version]...
```

and

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 2 and 3 different commits each, respectively....
```

But then some commands don't work at all and give the same error message, these include git log, git show and git diff for example.

Some examples:

```
$ git log
'': : command not found
```

and

```
$ git show
'': : command not found
```

And here's a strange one... If I run the git log command in a place which includes no repo, I get a message back from git

```
$ git log
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this is and any help would be much appreciated!

**Steps I've tried to solve it:**

1. Restarted the pc
2. reinstalled git and restarted
3. created a clean repo and tried the commands there

Comment: I don't actually know anything about git, but the `' ': : command not found` Looks like it thinks your 'command' was `' '`. It could be that it wants hyphens instead of spaces eg `git-show`

Comment: @Jonah Thanks for trying, but unfortunately that isn't it. With all git commands you first enter 'git' and then the command to be excecuted (also just double checked it with the man pages)